# Logistic function from 0 to 1 for input 0 to 1

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a function $f$ that looks like a [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) or [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function, but its function values should be
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = 1$$

I don't care about values $x < 0$, $x > 1$, $f(x) < 0$ and $f(x) > 1$, but between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ there should be a sigmoid-like curve:

[image]

The closest I came was with the logistic function:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{- 10(x -0.5  )}}$$

[image]

Anyone any better suggestions?

Comment: The incomplete beta function gives you two shape parameters to play with.

Comment: An odd polynomial (cubic or fifth order) would probably suffice.

Comment: $x^3(6x^2-15x+10)$ seems to be a good candidate. Ideally, you'd know what you wanted for derivatives and second derivatives at the midpoint and endpoints

Comment: If this is for ML, then you may want some tiny non zero derivative at 0 and 1, with 0 second derivative

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to take the logistic function, defined over an auxilliary variable z:

${\displaystyle f(z)={\frac {L}{1+e^{-k(z-z_{0})}}},}$

You take the L parameter to be $1$. Then you substitute $z$ and $z_0$ with a function $f(x)$, that is, $z = f(x)$,  such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = -\infty $ and
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} f(x) = \infty $. There may be many ways to do it (I am no mathematician) but one that is appropiate is $z = f(x) = \log(\frac{x}{1-x})$. After doing the composition you obtain:

${\displaystyle f(x)={\frac {1}{1+e^{-k\left(\log\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)-\log\left(\frac{x_0}{1-x_0}\right)\right)}}},}$

Which simplifies to:

${\displaystyle f(x)={\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{(1-x)x_0}{x(1-x_0)} \right)^k}},}$

For example for $x_0 = 0.5$ and $k = 2$ it looks like this

[Squeezed-Logistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyTCk.png)

The $x_0$ parameter indicates where the inflection point of the function lies, but for values other than $0.5$ it doesn't correspond exactly.

As a bonus for values of k between $0$ and $1$ the function looks like a logistic curve but with the axes flipped.

[Flipped Squeezed Logistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ2L9.png)

Hope this is useful.

Comment: The function works great but how have you figured out the conditions for z? """such that lim z [→0] = −∞ and lim z [→1] = +∞"""